# Two pointers alternative to C++ std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, boost, stdvector

In general `std::vector` object size is 24 bytes, as it is implemented as 3 pointers (each pointer is 8 bytes in size on 64-bit CPUs). These pointers are:

- begin of vector
- end of vector
- end of reserved memory for vector (vector capacity)

Do we have any similar container that offers same interface (**except for the capacity feature**) but is implemented only with two pointers (or perhaps a pointer + size value)?

It makes sense in some cases like my current project. I hold millions of vectors in memory, but I do not need the distinction between vector size and capacity, and memory usage is turning a bottleneck. I have considered a couple of options:

- `std::string` implementation may be tricky and include things like short string optimization, which may be even worse.
- `std::unique_ptr` to some allocated buffer. The interface is not so convenient as `std::vector`, and I would end up creating my own class that wraps the pointer plus size of the buffer, which is what I am trying to avoid.

So any ready made alternative? Boost libraries based solutions are accepted.

Comment: [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *"I do not need the distinction between vector size and capacity"*? Does your data structure need to be dynamically allocated, can it change its size?

Comment: For `std::array` you need to allocate its size at compilation time. As I said, what am I looking for is some alternative to `std::vector`, that exhibits same behaviour, but does not implement the capacity feature (i.e., size and capacity should be the same thing).

Comment: @Bob__ Indeed, I need it to be dynamically allocated. So far I do not need to change its size after dynamic allocation. But actually this could be possible even if the container is implemented only with two pointers (but we lose the convenience of having a reserved memory pointer).

Comment: `std::string` is an interesting alternative to consider. I did a quick check and while a `std::vector<char>` weighed in at 24 bytes, `std::string` was "only" 32 bytes (sizes may vary on other systems). Not really saving anything...

Comment: Implementing your own vector for pod types isn't particularly challenging

Comment: *"So far I do not need to change its size after dynamic allocation."* -- this might be an important detail to hammer down. If the size is known at construction time, much of the `std::vector` interface is no longer applicable. According to the question, you want everything but "the capacity feature", which I interpret as 4 of the 6 member functions that [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) lists under "Capacity". If you add in a fixed size, you can also eliminate the 9 "Modifiers" plus `assign` and `operator=`. You're up to 15 of the 33 methods eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the absolute minimum to encapsulate a `unique_ptr<T[]>` in a first-class value-type that models a [`RandomAccessRange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/range/RandomAccessRange):

```cpp
#include <memory>
template <typename T>
struct dyn_array {
    explicit dyn_array(size_t n)
      : _n(n), _data(std::make_unique<T[]>(n)) { }

    auto begin() const { return _data.get(); }
    auto end()   const { return begin() + _n; }
    auto begin()       { return _data.get(); }
    auto end()         { return begin() + _n; }
    auto size()  const { return _n; }
private:
    size_t _n {};
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> _data;
};
```

That's 15 lines of code. See it **[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/enjd8Y)**

```
int main() {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    for (int n; (n = size_gen(prng)) != 10;) {
        dyn_array<double> data(n);
        std::iota(begin(data), end(data), 0);

        static_assert(sizeof(data) == 2*sizeof(void*));

        fmt::print("Size {} data {}\n", n, data);
    }
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
Size 8 data {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
Size 6 data {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Size 7 data {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
Size 6 data {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I have commented two versions that

- add constructor guides with initializers [live](https://godbolt.org/z/rbqzTv)
- and add copy/move semantics [live](https://godbolt.org/z/TrYGfr)

### BONUS: Single Pointer Size

Building on the above, I realized that the size can be *inside* the allocation making the size of `dyn_array` **exactly 1 pointer**.

**[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qfchxG)**

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib> // committing the sin of malloc for optimization

template <typename T>
struct dyn_array {
    dyn_array(std::initializer_list<T> init)
    : _imp(allocate(init.size(), true))
    { std::uninitialized_move(init.begin(), init.end(), begin()); }

    dyn_array(dyn_array const& rhs)
    : _imp(allocate(rhs.size(), true))
    { std::uninitialized_copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin()); }

    dyn_array(dyn_array&& rhs)          { rhs.swap(*this); }
    dyn_array& operator=(dyn_array rhs) { rhs.swap(*this); } 

    explicit dyn_array(size_t n = 0)
    : _imp(allocate(n))
    { }

    auto size()  const { return _imp? _imp->_n : 0ull; }
    auto begin() const { return _imp? _imp->_data + 0 : nullptr; }
    auto begin()       { return _imp? _imp->_data + 0 : nullptr; }
    auto end()   const { return begin() + size(); }
    auto end()         { return begin() + size(); }
    auto empty() const { return size() == 0; }

    bool operator==(dyn_array const& rhs) const {
        return size() == rhs.size() &&
            std::equal(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
    };

    void swap(dyn_array& rhs) {
        std::swap(_imp, rhs._imp);
    }
private:
    struct Impl {
        size_t _n;
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
        T _data[]; // C99 extension
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    };
    struct Deleter {
        void operator()(Impl* s) const { 
            while (s->_n) { s->_data[--(s->_n)].~T(); }
            std::free(s);
        }
    };
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Impl, Deleter>;
    Ptr _imp;

    static Ptr allocate(size_t n, bool uninitialized = false) {
        if (!n)
            return {};

        auto p = std::malloc(sizeof(Impl) + n*sizeof(T)); // could be moreconservative
        auto s = Ptr(reinterpret_cast<Impl*>(p));
        s->_n = n;
        if (!uninitialized)
            std::uninitialized_default_construct_n(s->_data, n);
        return s;
    }
};
```

Which we can use as:

```
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

static size_t constructions = 0;
static size_t default_ctor, copy_ctor = 0;
static size_t destructions = 0;

struct Sensor final {
    Sensor()              { ++constructions; ++default_ctor; } 
    Sensor(Sensor const&) { ++constructions; ++copy_ctor; } 
    ~Sensor()             { ++destructions;  } 
};

int main() {
    fmt::print("With initializers: {}, {}\n",
        dyn_array{3.1415f},
        dyn_array{"one", "two", "three"});

    fmt::print("Without: {}, {}\n",
        dyn_array<std::string_view>{3}, 
        dyn_array<float>{1},
        dyn_array<int>{}); // empty by default, no allocation

    auto a = dyn_array{3,2,1};
    fmt::print("sizeof(a) == sizeof(void*)? {}\n", sizeof(a) == sizeof(void*));
    auto copy = a;
    fmt::print("copy: {} == {}? {}\n", copy, a, (copy == a));
    auto move = std::move(copy);
    fmt::print("move: {} == {}? {}\n", move, a, (move == a));
    fmt::print("copy now moved-from: {}, empty? {}\n", copy, copy.empty());

    dyn_array<Sensor>(4); // test destructors
    fmt::print("constructions({}) and destructions({}) match? {}\n",
            constructions, destructions, constructions == destructions);
    fmt::print("all default, no copy ctors? {}\n",
            (copy_ctor == 0) && (default_ctor == constructions));

    dyn_array { Sensor{}, Sensor{}, Sensor{} };
    fmt::print("constructions({}) and destructions({}) match? {}\n",
            constructions, destructions, constructions == destructions);
    fmt::print("initializers({}) were uninitialized-copied: {}\n",
            copy_ctor,
            (copy_ctor == 3) && (default_ctor + copy_ctor == constructions));
}
```

Printing:

```
With initializers: {3.1415}, {"one", "two", "three"}
Without: {"", "", ""}, {1}
sizeof(a) == sizeof(void*)? true
copy: {3, 2, 1} == {3, 2, 1}? true
move: {3, 2, 1} == {3, 2, 1}? true
copy now moved-from: {}, empty? true
constructions(4) and destructions(4) match? true
all default, no copy ctors? true
constructions(10) and destructions(10) match? true
initializers(3) were uninitialized-copied: true
```

> Of course you can do this without using [C99 flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), but I didn't want to meddle with alignment manually right now.

### BONUS: `[]` Indexing, `front`, `back`, `at` accessors

These are really simple to add:

```
auto& operator[](size_t n) const { return *(begin() + n); }
auto& operator[](size_t n)       { return *(begin() + n); }
auto& at(size_t n) const { return n<size()?*(begin() + n): throw std::out_of_range("dyn_array::at"); }
auto& at(size_t n)       { return n<size()?*(begin() + n): throw std::out_of_range("dyn_array::at"); }
auto& front() const { return at(0); }
auto& front()       { return at(0); }
auto& back()  const { return at(size()-1); }
auto& back()        { return at(size()-1); }
```

Of course push_back/erase/etc are out since the size doesn't change after construction.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. The vector I talk about is a data member of a class that is instanced millions times. I can use a `std::unique_ptr`, but I still need another separate variable to hold size of the buffer. The span solution you propose may be useful to abstract whatever implementation I use.

Comment: My point was to give you the building blocks. It should be pretty trivial to build your container on these primitives, but I'm not going to implement a vector-like interface just for an SO answer :)

Comment: If you want something ready-made that has a fixed size, consider `boost::container::static_vector` which you could then refer to by simple unique_ptr. It will have a size and capacity but because the latter is statically fixed, it will not be stored.

Comment: I think I did not make clear my purpose very well. Actually static vectors (or static extents) are something I do not need. Quite the opposite, all allocations are dynamic and size of vectors is unknown at compile time. Of course implementing my own vector like interface over an unique_ptr is not that difficult. But I was wondering if boost or the STL provide a ready-made solution. It is not about the difficulty of implementing such, but about being able to use some known container. That's always better than introducing my own one...

Comment: Oh it _was_ clear (this is why my answer did NOT suggest static vectors). As I made clear in my comment this was merely an alternative avenue "If you want something ready-made", because I got the impression that not having to implement the functionality yourself was the more important than the right building blocks.

Comment: I got inspired to show how quick it is to make something ready-made: [simplest
with full container/range semantics](https://godbolt.org/z/h38s9x). That's 15 lines of code _including the `#include`_. Of
course you might want [richer constructor guides](https://godbolt.org/z/rbqzTv). You can [make it movable/copyable](https://godbolt.org/z/TrYGfr) (this also throws in container equality comparison for demo(.

Comment: I just realized that by special-casing size==0 you can trim the footprint down to 1 pointer: [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/bxMEPx). Of course you can do this without using [C99 flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), but I didn't want to meddle with alignment manually right now.

Comment: Replaced my answer with the simpler and more complete takes. Thanks for making me go a step fruther. It's actually simpler (reinforcing the mantra: choosing the right abstractions leads to simplicity)

Comment: Cool idea, thanks. It is not hard to implement, but I got a couple of useful ideas from your code :) Actually, it wasn't about not having to implement it. It was just about using standard (or at least boost ones) containers. But it seems the only alternative is to use a custom implementation (even if 15 lines, it is still a custom container).

Comment: @sapito The http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3532.html proposal was reviewed but TTBOMK rejected (that isn't reflected in the https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-proposal-status.html so maybe there's a chance still?). And yeah, otherwise it's a custom container.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not need to change its size after dynamic allocation (from the comments)

Since you do not need your vectors to be expanded dynamically, [`std::valarray<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) may be a good alternative. Its size is fixed at construction, so the implementation does not need a third pointer.

Comment: Good point, but I still miss that it could easily replace a `std::vector` as long as I do not intend to call any capacity related methods. E.g., `std::valarray` does not have a `data()` member function.

Comment: @sapito well, `&v[0]` would yield the pointer to the initial element of both `std::vector<T>` and `std::valarray<T>`.

Comment: Yes, it is doable. Just wondering if there was something that could replace the `std::vector` and compile immediately without further changes to the code. Otherwise, yes, `valarray` is an alternative.